# Why am I getting a None value for all of my variables?

Tags: python, function, variables, arguments, nonetype

So, I've attempted to make a simple Base 10 to Base 16 converter (I realize this is Base 10 integer to a mock-Base 16 string). I'm fairly new to Python; I just started learning it this week (I have prior programming experience with C#, so I'm not lost on this).

```
R1 = 0
R2 = 0
R3 = 0
R4 = 0
R5 = 0

number = int(raw_input("Enter a base 10 number (Smaller than 1048576): "))

def numberConvert(a=0):
  a = str(a)

  if (a == "10"):
    a = "a"
  elif (a == "11"):
    a = "b"
  elif (a == "12"):
    a = "c"
  elif (a == "13"):
    a = "d"
  elif (a == "14"):
    a = "e"
  elif (a == "15"):
    a = "f"
  else:
    a = a

#Dividing

Q1 = (number // 16)
R1 = (number % 16)

Q2 = (Q1 // 16)
R2 = (Q1 % 16)

Q3 = (Q2 // 16)
R3 = (Q2 % 16)

Q4 = (Q3 // 16)
R4 = (Q3 % 16)

Q5 = (Q4 // 16)
R5 = (Q4 % 16)

R1 = numberConvert(R1)
R2 = numberConvert(R2)
R3 = numberConvert(R3)
R4 = numberConvert(R4)
R5 = numberConvert(R5)

print R1 + R2 + R3 + R4 + R5
```

After running and inputting 1048575 (that's the highest it can go, so I'm expecting **"fffff"** as an output), it gives me:

```
C:\PythonPrograms\Modules>Decimal_to_Hex.py
Enter a base 10 number (Smaller than 1048576): 1048575
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonPrograms\Modules\Decimal_to_Hex.py", line 50, in <module>
    print R1 + R2 + R3 + R4 + R5
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

After I ran some tests which mainly involved printing the `R1` to `R5` values at the beginning and the end of the function, I've come to the conclusion that the issue lies somewhere in the `R1 = numberConvert(R1)` section. At any time before that, the variables behave normally. Right at the start of the function, after being inputted, the`R` variables are numbers 0 through 15.

Right before function `numberConvert` finishes up, they are 0 through 9, or "a" through "f". However, if I were to print value `R1` immediately after `R1 = numberConvert(R1)`, it gives me `None` as an output.

From what I've read, this is essentially Python's null value. So, I've narrowed down the problem to the section where I'm running the function `numberConvert`.

Comment: Well you don't actually *return* anything from your function.

Comment: And why are you converting to a string in the beginning? Why not compare with the *number* `15` (for example)? If you want to return a string, then do the string-conversion when returning the value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All functions in Python return `None` by default unless you have a [return-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return_stmt).  So, if you want your `numberConvert` function to return a value other than `None`, you need to put one:

```
def numberConvert(a=0):
  a = str(a)

  if (a == "10"):
    a = "a"
  elif (a == "11"):
    a = "b"
  elif (a == "12"):
    a = "c"
  elif (a == "13"):
    a = "d"
  elif (a == "14"):
    a = "e"
  elif (a == "15"):
    a = "f"
  else:
    a = a

  ########
  return a
  ########
```

---

Since you say you have C# experience, perhaps you thought that doing:

```
R1 = numberConvert(R1)
```

would pass `R1` as a reference which would be modified inside `numberConvert` whenever you did:

```
a = ...
```

This is incorrect though because `a` is treated as a local name that gets assigned the value of `R1`.  For more information on this, see [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/2555451)

---

Also, there are a few things I'd like to mention about your `numberConvert` function:

1. You do not need parenthesis with if-statements in Python.  In fact, most Python programmers consider them to be bad style. Instead, you should just do:

   ```
   if a == "10":
     a = "a"
   elif a == "11":
     a = "b"
   ...
   ```
2. There is not really a reason to do:

   ```
   a = str(a)
   ```

   since you can compare with integers directly:

   ```
   if a == 10:
     a = "a"
   elif a == 11:
     a = "b"
   ```
3. If you want, you could use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) to avoid all those if-statements:

   ```
   def numberConvert(a=0):
       return {"10":"a","11":"b","12":"c","13":"d","14":"e","15":"f"}.get(a, a)
   ```

Comment: Ahh, I see now; I've just had a habit to use parenthesis as organization more than anything.